# Is there a maximum size for NextJs API routes res.json({}) body size on Vercel production?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, vercel

I've been struggling with an issue on NextJs. I'm using the `pdfKit` library to generate PDFs in a base64 format. Everything works well on development mode, but at Vercel's production, the server is returning a `500` status without any error message. Here is the code were I'm returning the pdfs converted in base64:

```
console.log(`Sending ${couponPdfs.length} pdfs to client.`);
res.status(200).json({ couponPdfs });
```

In my logs it is printing the actual `couponPdfs` length, so I don't know why it is returning a `500` status code. If I change the response to `res.status(200).json({ couponPdfs: [] });` works fine, so it must be something with the size of the generated pdfs in the json object, in this example I'm generating 20 pdfs.

Comment: "The maximum payload size for the request body or the response body of a Serverless Function is 5 MB." from [Vercel Limits documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/platform/limits#serverless-function-payload-size-limit). API routes become isolated serverless functions in Vercel.